# problem when installing pyobjc in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, python

```
tsheri@tsheri-Aspire-E5-576G:~/Downloads/driver-drowsiness/drowsiness-detection$ conda activate driverenv
(driverenv) tsheri@tsheri-Aspire-E5-576G:~/Downloads/driver-drowsiness/drowsiness-detection$ pip install pyobjc
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting pyobjc
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/56/6a2ae9f35aeb04acd2b881fde77985629b1c92e2b89e112021e2580f5687/pyobjc-5.2-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting pyobjc-framework-CoreServices==5.2 (from pyobjc)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/e1/4637afdb254719905adbf073e3bc3843f408944d31b4e21506bf8436c712/pyobjc-framework-CoreServices-5.2.tar.gz (409kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 419kB 333kB/s 
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python2 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vLRgWU/pyobjc-framework-CoreServices/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vLRgWU/pyobjc-framework-CoreServices/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-vLRgWU/pyobjc-framework-CoreServices/
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-vLRgWU/pyobjc-framework-CoreServices/setup.py", line 23, in <module>
        extra_link_args=['-framework', 'CoreServices']),
      File "pyobjc_setup.py", line 392, in Extension
        os_level = get_os_level()
      File "pyobjc_setup.py", line 206, in get_os_level
        pl = plistlib.readPlist('/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 75, in readPlist
        pathOrFile = open(pathOrFile)
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist'
```

Comment: Did you try with `python3-pip`?

Comment: I tried but it produce same error.

Comment: I don't know ho w but despite those errors i tried many times and while still having that error i checked pip freeze which shows it has been installed but it was not before but anyway its working now